# 6A Current Source

Tags: current, source

Hi I am designing a 6A current source. I know how to design a current source I am just looking for suggested materials that can handle the full 6A. The op amps and transistors that I have now are more on the milliamp side so I just am looking for something beefier.

Comment: I've flagged this question as off-topic because it's asking for specific part recommendations. (Have you tried searching Digikey and similar sites? Their search pages are made so that you can specify current ratings, etc...)

Comment: -1 because if you "know how to design a current source", then you know why you haven't given us near enough information to help you with part selection. (For a start, how about a schematic showing which type of current source you are designing).

Comment: A very important aspect that you omit is how much voltage your current source must be able to devilver. For a linear circuit, that determines the amount of power that must be dissipated.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I am an EE student working in a startup and cant give many or any details as to what is being designed. Thanks for the help I will definitely check out Digikey.

Comment: "cant give many or any details as to what is being designed" Phooey. You don't need to describe the exact application, but refusing to discuss the characteristics of the load and the voltage requirements is paranoia run amok. The folks here aren't your competitors (or if they are they don't know it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg hit the nail on the head. If you go to digikey, you can use their filtering tools to get what you want. Start with "transistor" followed by NPN or PNP, depending on what you want. Then filter on the current you need. I'm sure you'll find some options.

If you're looking for something super simple and don't care about power loss, look for a transistor in a TO-3 package along with a good size heat sink and hardware for mounting.

A SMPS is a good idea if it's in your price range. While these are great, they can be a pain and/or very expensive for the hobbyist. Sometimes digikey will also sell assembled demo boards, which can be a good compromise between cost and efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use a switching regulator to avoid heat issues. There are many switching regulators on the market. You can hack together a circuit to make them regulate current.

However, there are specialized switching regulators that are *meant* for use as constant-current sources. These are often marketed as **LED Drivers**. If you simply look for these, you will find a wide selection of switching regulators that will satisfy your requirements without modification. [This one](http://www.linear.com/product/LT8613) looks perfect.